# With AG Grid, prevent row click event when cell is clicked?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'd like to stop event propagation on all cell clicks since I'm using `onRowClicked` to do some actions. When a user clicks on something inside a cell (like an input field), I don't want the row click to be triggered.

Any thoughts?

I'm using Angular 2/4 for this.

Answer (score 11):

None of the past suggestions worked for me. AG Grid may have changed the API behavior. Even `event.stopPropagation()` on `onCellClicked` would not stop `onRowClicked` from firing.

What I ultimately did was to remove `onRowClicked` altogether and handle everything in `onCellClicked`. `onRowClicked` does not have an attribute on which column the click event generated from, `onCellClicked` does!

```js
function cellClickedHandler(e) {
  if (e.column.colId === 'col1') {
    // Handle specific cell
  } else {
    // Handle all other cells, similar to rowClicked
  }
}
```

Comment: `e` from above is type of `CellClickedEvent` where colId is not accessible due to being private. Use instead `getColId()`.

Answer (score 5):

```
  <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%;   height: 168px;" class="ag-theme-fresh" 
    [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [enableFilter]="true" [enableSorting]="true" 
    [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" 
    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    (cellClicked)='onCellClicked($event)'>
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Use  `[suppressRowClickSelection]="true"` to prevent the row click

Comment: This actually is a **workaround**. What if we want to enable selection while clicking a row, and also have `(rowClicked)` event?

Comment: if that is the case then add (rowSelected)="onRowClicked($event)"
(rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)",                                                               
    in the method  in                                        
                                                                                            
     if(( event.type == 'rowSelected')) {}                                                                              like this put a condition and do.

Comment: This works well. You just need to capture the event of the onclick and then you can use event.colDef.colId to check the column. If it matches what you want then you can do your logic including setting the row to be selected or clicked.